# Interface de Arrays e Strings PHP

Tags: php, array, string

### **Situação**

Tenho uma página em PHP que faz pesquisas de CNPJ e retorna os valores, porém como está sem formatação nenhuma os resultados aparecem em formas de `ARRAY` e `STRINGS`.

### **Exemplo**

```
    array(23) { [0]=> string(18) "XX.XXX.XXX/XXXX-XX" [1]=> string(10) 
    "XX/XX/XXXX" [2]=> string(58) "EMPRESA XXXXXXXX" [3]=> string(10) 
    "FANTASIA" [4]=> string(90) "DESCRIÇÃO" [5]=> array(2) { [0]=> 
    string(67) "4X.5X-2-0X - XXXXXXXXXX SERVIÇOS " [1]=> string(80) 
    "XX.11-X-00 - Atuação XXXXXXXX" } [6]=> string(68) "230-5 - 
    EMPRESA INDIVIDUAL DE RESP.LIMITADA (DE NATUREZA EMPRESARIA)" 
    [7]=> string(37) "R XXXXXXXXXX (JD XX)" [8]=> string(2) "55" 
    [9]=> string(0) "" [10]=> string(10) "09.XX0-XXX" [11]=> string(15) 
    "XXX BAIRRO" [12]=> string(21) "XXX XXXX XX XXX" [13]=> string(2) 
    "XX" [14]=> string(26) "xxxxxxxxx@xx.com.br" [15]=> string(14) 
    "(1x) XXXX-XXXX" [16]=> string(5) "*****" [17]=> string(5) "ATIVA" 
    [18]=> string(10) "XX/03/XXXX" [19]=> string(0) "" [20]=> string(8)
     "********" [21]=> string(8) "********" ["status"]=> string(2) "OK" }
```

### **O que exatamente quer?**

Não procuro nada mastigado, apenas quero uma direção, por onde começar. Mais especificamente eu gostaria de saber como posso especificar para um certo espaço chamar uma certa string, por exemplo: uma caixa de texto que dentro dela vai ter a string 8.

### **Resumo do Resumo**

Alocar Array e String em um local determinado.

**Espero que tenha dado pra entender**, caso eu consiga ter uma ideia melhor de como posso explicar, eu edito a pergunta.

Comment: Não entendi nada. Poderia tentar explicar novamente?

Comment: O que tens ai no exemplo não é mais que um array com tamanho 23. Por exemplo, `[0]=> string(18) "XX.XXX.XXX/XXXX-XX"`, na posição 0 tens uma string com tamanho 18 que é "XX.XXX.XXX/XXXX-XX" e por ai fora... `array[0] = "XX.XXX.XXX/XXXX-XX"`

Comment: Que tal colocar na questão o código que você atualmente usa pra formatar a saida? Pode ajudar a deixar mais clara a sua necessidade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acho que você está confundindo, aquela "*string(n)*" que aparece mostra apenas o tamanho dos caracteres que estão dentro de cada índice do array.

Se eu entendi bem, acredito que você está querendo mostrar um único índice do array separadamente. Se for esse o caso com o seguinte array distribuído assim:

```
$array = array(
    [0] => "a",
    [1] => "b",
    [2] => "c",
    [3] => "d"
);
```

ou assim:

```
$array = array([0] => "a", [1] => "b", [2] => "c", [3] => "d");
```

é só chamar o indice que você quer:

```
//o resultado seria "b"
echo $array[1];
```

Espero ter ajudado;

Att;

Comment: é isso mesmo, me desculpe pela má explicação, mas você interpretou bem, exatamente isso. Agradeço @fleuquer-lima

Comment: Sem problemas, já passei pela mesma situação... =P. Qualquer duvida que eu  puder ajudar estou a disposição.